# Center title of chart relative to the plot background

Tags: highcharts

I would like to center the title of a pie chart relative to the plot background (not the element containing the chart), so that if there is a legend next to the char the title is still centered relative to the pie.

Using

```
    title: {
        text: 'Title',
        align: 'center'
    }
```

centers the title relative to the containing element.
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrdeobw1/1/) for the full example.

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the title in the `render` event, for example:

```
chart: {
  ...,
  events: {
    render: function() {
      var seriesGroupBBox = this.seriesGroup.getBBox();

      this.title.attr({
        x: seriesGroupBBox.x + seriesGroupBBox.width / 2 - this.title.getBBox().width / 2
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6a9sroe7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: It's a good solution, it doesn't work for me, though. I have several other config settings which probably interferes with this one. I suspect the responsive config...

Comment: Hi @Katona, I can look at your problem if you provide me with the full working example in jsfiddle.